# React native date time picker ios

Tags: react-native, nsdate, react-native-ios

I am learning react native and started a project. I need to use datetime picker for ios and i found a modal datetimepicker but the problem is this picker returns me 'Tue Jul 17 2018 15:46:26 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)' nsdate format but i want to 'yyyy-mm-dd:hh:mm:ss' format. How can i handle this, any suggestion ?

i am using https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use momentjs.com library to make your custom time format.

İyi şanslar!

Comment: and i saw now. Teşekkür derim!